# What does ' but it is not installable' mean?

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

I noticed when I try some packages, I get sometimes this error:

```
<pkg_name> Depends: <an_other_pkg> (>= version X.X.X) but it is not installable.
```

What does is mean '  but it is not installable.' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<pkg> Depends: <an_other_pkg> (>= version X.X.X) but it is not installable
```

This  package depends on other package version X.X.X which isn't installable because the needed package is no longer available in the repositories. So it is not installable.

Comment: Does that mean all what I have to do is to edit /etc/apt/sources.list with the appropriate repository ?

Comment: yep. But older version of packages are not maintained. You have to add the repository or PPA which contains that needed specific version.