# How to download a package with dependency manually?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I am going to install following package: gcc-4.9-aarch64-linux-gnu

But apt is unable to find it. I downloaded the .deb manually and installed it using dpkg. but there is some missing dependency. When I use apt to fix the problem it said:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9-aarch64-linux-gnu
        Reading package lists... Done
        Building dependency tree       
        Reading state information... Done
        gcc-4.9-aarch64-linux-gnu is already the newest version (4.9.3-13ubuntu2cross1).
        You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
        The following packages have unmet dependencies:
         gcc-4.9-aarch64-linux-gnu : Depends: cpp-4.9-aarch64-linux-gnu (= 4.9.3-13ubuntu2cross1) but it is not installable
                                     Depends: binutils-aarch64-linux-gnu (>= 2.26)
                                     Depends: gcc-4.9-aarch64-linux-gnu-base (= 4.9.3-13ubuntu2cross1) but it is not installable
                                     Depends: libgcc-4.9-dev-arm64-cross (= 4.9.3-13ubuntu2cross1) but it is not installable
                                     Depends: libmpfr4 (>= 3.1.3) but it is not installable
                                     Recommends: libc6-dev-arm64-cross (>= 2.13-0ubuntu6) but it is not going to be installed
        E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

What does it mean by `but it is not installable` ? Why I can not install it? I have been added all 4 main repositories from Ubuntu. I am using ubuntu 18.04.

EDIT: I have seen this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488412/what-does-but-it-is-not-installable-mean). BUT I want to install it anyway. How I can? The problem with manual installation is its many dependency packages. Should I download and install all of them manually? Not less tedious way?!

Comment: If you install things outside the repositories, you then are responsible for manually finding, downloading, and installing the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually find the packages by searching [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com).  For instance you can follow the links to get to a downloadable deb of one of the dependecies from here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/xenial/cpp-4.9-aarch64-linux-gnu.

There might be an easier way though.  Since this appears to be from Xenial, if you turn off all repos in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and only have the `main` and `universe` repos enabled for Xenial (eg. `deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main universe`), then perhaps `apt-get install gcc-4.9-aarch64-linux-gnu` will work.  Make sure to do `apt remove gcc-4.9-aarch64-linux-gnu` first.  Also, be careful, make sure that only the dependencies you want are getting pulled in.  Sometimes this kind of thing can end up trying to install the Xenial `glibc`, which could break your system.